# Combination selecting a vocal group

Tags: combinatorics

*A vocal group consisting of alf,bill,cal,deb,eve, and fay (3 boys and 3 girls) are deciding how to arrange themselves from left to right on a stage.*

How many way to do this if

A. The boys should be next to each other and so should the girls?

B. Just the boys sit next to each other?

*For A I am having problem solving.*

The seating I can come up with BBBGGG or GGGBBB. I think it would would be

$(3!)(3!)$ That is 36 possible ways.

For part B it would similar to A since there equal amount of boys and girls.

So the possibilities are

BBB GGG

But I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first calculation is almost right. You need to multiply by $2$. For there are $36$ ways using the pattern BBBGGG, and $36$ for GGGBBB.

For boys all together, there are several patterns: BBBGGG, GBBBGG, and so on. Count the number of patterns and multiply by $3!3!$.

Comment: I see so you have to pay attention to the edges.

Comment: Both problems have the same basic structure. But if you only need the boys to be together, there are more "sex alternation" patterns than in the case boys are all together **and** girls are all together.

Comment: So  BBGGBB would not count as pattern, because in BBBGGG a boy and girl stand next to each other in the BG part, so I guess the main idea is that no boy can have a girl sitting to his left and right.

Comment: In BBGGBB which is probably a typo, there are too many boys, and they are not all together. There are $4$ "good" patterns in all, $0$ to $3$ girls on the left end.

Comment: I see so the pattern are GGGBBB,GGBBBG,GBBBGG,BBBGGG. I think because all three boys have to be togheter.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Another way of thinking about it is that you have the clump $\mathfrak{B}$ of boys, and $3$ girls. The clump can be in any of $4$ places.